# Change JSESSIONID cookie if the login is successful

Tags: java, redirect, session-cookies, jsessionid

For security purposes, upon successful logon, I need to change the JSESSIONID. I have something below. But it seems that, JSESSIONID is changed upon successful logon. But when I navigate to other pages, the JSESSIONID is changed again. I could not figure out what is wrong.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String _LOC = "[Redirect Filter: doFilter]";

    SB_UtilityLocal UTIL = createSB_UtilityLocal();

    boolean authorized = false;

    String user_sys_id = null;
    HttpSession oldsession = null;
    HttpSession session = null;     

    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        oldsession = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);

        if (oldsession != null) {
            // make a copy of the session content
            Map<String, Object> temp = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
            Enumeration e = oldsession.getAttributeNames();
            while (e != null && e.hasMoreElements()) {
                String name = (String) e.nextElement();
                Object value = oldsession.getAttribute(name);
                temp.put(name, value);
            }

            // kill the old session and create a new one
            oldsession.invalidate();
            session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();

            // copy back the session content
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> stringObjectEntry : temp.entrySet()) {
                session.setAttribute(stringObjectEntry.getKey(),
                        stringObjectEntry.getValue());
            }           

            if (session != null) {
                user_sys_id = (String) session.getAttribute("user_sys_id");
                if (user_sys_id != null) {
                    authorized = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to call this only after logon, it seems that this filter runs for each page. You can read the controller which is being called and filter by that.

Comment: @SimoneZandara I see. Instead of putting it at doFilter, I am thinking of putting it at the end of the login method. Do you see any issue with that?

Comment: You can try that solution as well, that depends a bit on your login flow. If you expect the Cookie to be changed later in the future (ie. after AutoLogin) then the end of the login method might not be the best place.

Comment: @SimoneZandara Thanks for the hint! After I put it at the end of the login method, it works as expected now. :)